# Why does async_read in boost asio has const MutableBufferSequence as the second arguments?

Tags: c++, boost, constants

The boost asio library has async_read function.

```
    template<
        typename AsyncReadStream,
        typename MutableBufferSequence,
        typename ReadHandler>
    void-or-deduced async_read(
        AsyncReadStream & s,
        const MutableBufferSequence & buffers,
        ReadHandler handler);
```

This function is used to asynchronously read a certain number of bytes of data from a stream. And the result will put in the second argument MutableBufferSequence. What does the const mean? Cause the buffer will be modified soon?

Comment: So that you can pass anything that models the MutableBufferSequence concept. Which means you can use any compatible sequence of mutable buffers.

Comment: Oh. The const part. `MutableBufferSequence` acts like a reference. The  reference is not modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MutableBufferSequence` is a container of `MutableBuffer`s. A `MutableBuffer` is a reference to a fixed-length area of mutable memory. Note that it does not in itself contain the memory.

During the call, the MutableBufferSequence is copied (maybe more than once) and stored in the asynchronous operation.

Note that the only things being copied are references to areas of mutable memory, not memory itself.

Comment: You mean during the call, the buffer is not modified. And it's reference is copied to async operation. When the data is ready, the areas of memory will be modified. But this happends after the function's life.

Comment: The container is not modified. That means that the *count* of buffers can't change. The elements can (apparently) be modified even through `const` references. That means the *content* can change

Comment: Buffers has reference semantics, much like `string_view` or `reference_wrapper`. Much like you can mutate the int pointed to by `int * const` you can mutate the buffer "pointed to" by a const copy of the reference. _(It's the reference that is const, not the type pointed to)_